# Retrieve the selected record

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with 9 columns and X rows. When I double-click a cell it displays its contents. How should I change the code to view, with a double-click, the entire row, i.e. the whole record?

```
class Searchtable(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab = QTableWidget(0,9,self)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(8,130)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(7,70)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(6,70)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(5,130)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(4,50)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(3,60)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(2,100)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(1,130)
        self.tab.setColumnWidth(0,130)
        self.tab.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tab.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tab.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.doubleclick_Recordfound)

        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(hbox1)

    def doubleclick_Recordfound(self):
        print(self.tab.currentItem().text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal `itemDoubleClicked` send the item pressed, from that item you can get the row so it's just a matter of iterating:

```py
@pyqtSlot("QTableWidgetItem*")
def doubleclick_Recordfound(self, item):
    r = item.row()
    for c in range(self.tab.columnCount()):
        it = self.tab.item(r, c)
        if it is not None:
            print(it.text())
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this 'item' sending.